# Java 8 Streams - Get distinct integers from object list as an array

Tags: arrays, java-8, java-stream

I'm struggling to work out how to get the distinct integers from an object list as an array using Streams.

Consider I have the below class:

```
public class Person{

    private int age;
    private double height;

    public Person(int age, double height) {
        this.age= age;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Then consider that have a populated list of these objects e.g. `List<Person> people`.

My question is, how do I use Java streams to extract the distinct ages into a Int array?

What I have so far is:

```
List<Integer> distinctAge = people.stream().distinct().mapToInt().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge));
```

Obviously that doesn't compile but I'm hitting a wall as to where to go next.

Once I have this array, I'm planning to grab all the objects from the list which contain the distinct value - I assume this is also possible using Streams?

Comment: If you read what you wrote it would be on the lines of, *create a stream of people, then find distinct values amongst them, follow with mapping them to Integer and finally collect these as the result.* Revisit this thought and see what all you have to rectify, that might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can collect all ages using [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and the call [distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) for distinct values

```
Integer[] ages = persons.stream()
            .map(Person::getAge)
            .distinct()
            .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

If you want to collect into `int[]`

```
int[] ages = persons.stream()
            .mapToInt(Person::getAge)
            .distinct()
            .toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use Set instead of using distinct as it improve performance.

```
Set<Integer> ages = persons.stream().map(Person::getAge).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do I use Java streams to extract the distinct ages
> into a Int array?
>
> Once I have this array, I'm planning to grab all the objects from the
> list which contain the distinct value - I assume this is also possible
> using Streams?

Paraphrasing this problem,

You need a Map<Integer,List> where key of the map is the age and the value is a List of Person of that particular age.

```
Map<Integer, List<Person>> agePersonMap =
        people.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge));
```